# Maven project dependencies vs project's plugins dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pmd

Can dependencies defined in project affect plugins dependencies executed on project ? When I execute PMD via plugin on multi-module project, it fails with NPE on first submodule, but when executed directly from failing submodule directory, it succeds.

EDIT:
stacktrace from maven:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd (default-cli) on project ......... : Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd failed.: NullPointerExceptio
n -> [Help 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd (default-cli) on project ........ : Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven
-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)                                                                                                                   
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)                                                                                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)                                                                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)                                                                                                                                                                             
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                                                                                                           
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                                                                   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)                                                                                                                                                     
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)                                                                                                                                                             
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)                                                                                                                                                   
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)                                                                                                                                                               
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.8:pmd failed.                                                                                            
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)                                                                                                                   
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)                                                                                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)                                                                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)                                                                                                                                                                             
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                                                                                                           
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                                                                   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)                                                                                                                                                     
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)                                                                                                                                                             
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)                                                                                                                                                   
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)                                                                                                                                                               
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.readProperties (PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.java:113)                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.read (PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.java:100)                                                                                                                           
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.read (PropertiesFactoryConfiguration.java:94)                                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.read (ConfigurationUtils.java:436)                                                                                                                                                   
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.findInFileSystem (ConfigurationUtils.java:328)                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.getAutoLoaded (ConfigurationUtils.java:208)                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.autoConfigure (ToolManager.java:74)                                                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init> (ToolManager.java:68)                                                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init> (ToolManager.java:59)                                                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.createVelocityContext (DefaultSiteRenderer.java:435)                                                                                                                             
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.generateDocument (DefaultSiteRenderer.java:573)                                                                                                                                  
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute (AbstractMavenReport.java:153)                                                                                                                                                    
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)                                                                                                                                       
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)                                                                                                                                                         
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)                                                                                                                   
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)                                                                                                                                                                            
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)                                                                                                                                                                                
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)                                                                                                                                                                                   
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)                                                                                                                                                                             
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                                                                                                           
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                                                                   
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)                                                                                                                                                     
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)                                                                                                                                                             
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)                                                                                                                                                   
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)                                                                                                                                                               
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:                                                                                                                                       
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Version of site plugin could affect it ? I have specified 2.2 version

Comment: could you add more details like your parent pom and the failing modules pom? also a stacktrace  would help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,after debbuging Maven execution I found that project have custom  tools.properties that colides with Apache Velocity used internally by Maven